# Are there some good CSS practices in order to avoid browser-compatibility issues with IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've discover so far that:

- stating the `width` in some elements fix issues in IE.
- and of course using a CSS reset

Do you know any others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that manually setting `width` would more often than not break things in IE, as a lot of IE versions implement a flawed box model.

I'd also say that a lot of all browser incompatibilities originate from a sub par understanding of the box model and float/clear, block/inline.

Having said that, I of course do not deny that it is IE, rather than the developer, that is the real problem, but I usually seek to avoid browser incompatibilities by using HTML structures that not even IE could miss-interpret, rather than through CSS hacks, and I've found that that is often quite doable.

Comment: how can I find out which HTML structures IE can't miss-interpret?

Comment: @janoChen: granted, they're not a lot, hey? well there's a lot of trial and error involved, i guess, to get to a place where you habitually write code that'll work cross-browser. x1a4's remark on doctype is especially important. when working with fixed widths, having a container of that width, and applying margin to the child content, instead of having a container of width x and padding on that, will avoid differences in box model implementation. instead of `min-height` you could place a 1px left-floated div of that height inside the element. only float the elements that need to float.

Comment: a lot of the times it'll work better to clear manually rather than having the elements just wrap due to lack of space. a solid understanding of wrapping when dealing with floats is also good to have. for instance it is a lot of times better to place a right-floated element before left-floated ones, even if after would make intuitively more sense. understand that elements must sometimes contain something in order to occupy any physical space *at all* in IE, and that adding an `&nbsp;` to fix that will cause the element to occupy the full height of a space character.

Comment: a lot of the times, positioning of elements relatively to one another is best achieved with a `position: relative` parent, leaving `top` and `left` unset, and absolutely positioned children. and it is of course helpful to understand the implications of different positionings, on how the element occupies space in its container.

Answer (score 2):

- Learn about [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)
- Inline block behavior can be achieved on IE7 by turning on hasLayout, then setting display to inline. This has turned out to be quite useful to me.
- Make sure your doctype is present and correct. This alone can save hours of pain.
- Use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) anytime you need to hack something especially for IE. PLEASE don't fall into the amateur's habit of adding star/underscore junk in your main stylesheet.